# How to properly use a tests folder in a rust project

Tags: rust

I have a cargo project called `data-structures-in-rust` that im implementing all data structures that I implemented in C when I was in college.

The current structure is:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── ll
    │   ├── implementation.rs
    │   ├── mod.rs
    │   └── node.rs
    ├── main.rs
    └── tests
        └── ll.rs
```

In `src/main.rs` I used well my ll structures, but now I just want to write unit tests. I have read plenty of tests/modules documentations but I just dont get it.

Cargo isnt recognizing my tests module. When I run `cargo test` it shows me:

```
test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

In tests/ll.rs I have:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
use super::ll::implementation::LList;

#[test]
fn create_list() {
    let list = LList::new(1);
    assert_eq!(list.head.data, 1);
}
```

Besides that, rust-analyzer in my IDE arent recognizing this too. In this `create_list` simple test for example, my IDE cant infer the `list` type. So I imagine that cargo isnt looking to `test/*` as a module.

Should I create a `mod.rs` in `tests/`?  What am I missing here?

Comment: Normally you `#[cfg(test)]` around a `mod tests { ... }`.

Comment: Remember you can put tests inside your individual source files, or in separate files, or both.

Comment: There is a pattern? Like, normally community creates a "global" tests module and inside it puts submodules to test all app modules, or inside each app module put a submodule test to test it locally...

Comment: The pattern is likely what `cargo create` gives you, and people just build on that. There's also a case to be made for separate tests, if that's what you're used to, or if they're more integration related and not specific to any one unit. It's up to you to organize, but there's tons of open-source Rust projects to look at and learn from.

Comment: Oh I see it now. With folder `/tests/` with a `mod.rs` file inside, I need to declare `mod tests` in `src/main.rs` file... Now it all works.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't import it in `main` then it doesn't "exist" as far as the compiler's concerned.

Comment: From your question and your comments, it looks like you don't understand modules in Rust well, which probably means you're a beginner (still! not a bad thing!). Yet you want to implement data structures in Rust. So I have one recommendation for you: DON'T. This won't teach you good or idiomatic Rust. This will just confuse you and make you stare at the computer.

Comment: Some data structure, like singly linked lists or trees without parent pointers, are nice and easy to implement in Rust, if done correctly. Others, most of them, are _really hard_ and require unsafe code to implement properly. So, implementing data structures in Rust is a great idea and a great challenge, _after_ you've already mastered Rust. In the meantime, pick some other Rust project to experiment with (how about a ray tracer)?

Comment: And I already saw it mentioned, but I had to mention the great book [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) (of course, for later, _after_ you will already master Rust). It makes a really good job teaching linked lists in Rust, and will also teach you some things about data structures in Rust in general. Another really important data structure is `Vec`, and [the nomicon has a good chapter on implementing it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/vec/vec.html). It touches lots of sharp edges with unsafe code in Rust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust supports three types of [tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html): unit, doc, and integration.

Unit tests go in the *src* directory with the rest of your code. Any function annotated with `#[test]` will be included as a unit test, and these are often grouped into a test module for organization.

For example, at the end of `ll/mod.rs`, you can have this.

```rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::implementation::LList;

    #[test]
    fn create_list() {
        let list = LList::new(1);
        assert_eq!(list.head.data, 1);
    }
}
```

You can find your public items the same way you would in any module, with `use super::LList` or whatever path works for you.

[Doc tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/write-documentation/documentation-tests.html) are like integration tests (below), but are written into your documentation.

Integration tests live in the *tests* directory, next to *src* and *Cargo.toml*. They use your crate as if they include it as a dependency. You can find your items under the crate name.

```rs
use data_structures_in_rust::implementation::LList;
```

---

P.S. Since you mentioned linked lists, be sure to look at [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: It doesnt work, I think my lack of knowlegde here is how modules works in rust, its just so anti intuitive to me. I edited my post, so if you read it again i would be very grateful

Comment: @TâmerCuba do you want unit tests or integration tests?

Comment: Unit tests. But it get it now. My lack of knowledge was that if I do not declare a module on `main.rs` it "doesnt exist" to the compiler, so cargo was ignoring my module test. But you really help me to find that answer, ty